# How can I use inversion method for simulating max function of a Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: r, simulation

I want to generate of the random variable `M` which

```
M = max{k>=0 : B_k=1}
```

and `B_k`  has the Bernoulli distribution with mean `p_k`.

How can I use with inversion method for generating in R programming?

Comment: why do you want to use the inversion method? It is simpler to generate the `B_k` and then to compute `M`.

Comment: I want to use inversion method because M is a random variable with distribution F(M).

Comment: Yes I know. I am just saying it is simpler to generate B_k first and then to compute M. No need for the inversion method

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention this, but presumably you repeat the Bernoulli experiment *n* times. Then the remaining *n-k* values `B_i` are zero, and thus *n-k* is distributed according to the geometric distribution. You can thus generat your random numbers as

```
n - rgeom(number, p)
```

Comment: Do you mean binomial distribution?

Comment: No, it is the geometric distribution. The OP is looking for the *maximum* k that is one, whcich is the same as reversing the order and looking for the *minimum* (or *first*) k, which is distributed according to the geometric distribution. It seems, though, that the OP lost interest in his/her question...